# Merging 2 close lines

Tags: c#, math, image-processing

How can I merge 2 lines and take the longest length? 2 close lines that I need to merge

[image: 2 close lines that I need to merge]

what I have tried:

1. I translated 2 close lines to the origin
2. rotate it down to Ox-axes
3. Compare the length of 2 lines( I think this step I made mistakes).
   3.1. I project endpoints of line 2( I call the line at original is line 1) down to Ox. Then I'll take 2 endpoints that create the longest length.
   3.2. Here I only compare 5 cases

- Case 1:

  [image: case 1]
- Case 2:

  [![case 2][3]][3]
- Case 3:

  [image: case 3]
- Case 4:

  [image: case 4]
- case 5:

  [image: case 5]

4. Rotate back to the original orientation
5. Move it back to the original order

Here is the result

[image: result]

As you can see the length is not what I wanted to get. I think there is a mathematical problem.

You can test it by simply adding these 4 coordinates:
Line 1: (544,297) (598,19)
Line 2: (546,314) (583,122)
Line 3: (205,432) (340,449)
Line 4: (227,227) (340,450)

Edit: Sorry I forgot to post my code here. This is the first time I use github, I am sorry if it is not easy to see my code, please tell me about that as well, and I will fix this. Thank you.

https://github.com/hailuu684/D-BME_MSc_semester_2-Github-code/blob/main/HoughLine%20transform%20and%20%20merging%20lines

Edit 1: when I apply this method to another image, there is still a problem. I've been thinking for days, but still cannot come up with any idea.
[there is still an error like I had above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqcWL.png)

Comment: can you share the code you've got so far?

Comment: are you getting this data as images, or do you have the points that compose each line? If it's the latter, can you share that with us?

Comment: @lucasreta Yes I have edited my post, please check it

Comment: @lan Chu: Yes, the input is an image. I used houghlinesP to find the lines on an image, but what I received is so many parallel lines, so I wanna combine it into just 1 line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Xa < Xb` and `Xc < Xd`, the length of overlap is given by

```
min(Xb, Xd) - max(Xa, Xc)
```

From this value, as well as from the individual segment lengths and their distance, you can decide to merge or not. (If the value is negative, the segments do not overlap at all).

If you merge, the new endpoints are given by

```
Xl= min(Xa, Xc), Xr= max(Xb, Xd)
```

Comment: Can you suggest the best method for merging these lines? because If I apply your solution to another image, there is still a problem. I will upload it on the editing part.

Comment: @HaiLuu: I am no wizard. I can't guess how you messed with your code.